# find command with regex quantifier e.g. {1,2}

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression

I have been trying to create a find command string that will find all files that end with a number 1-99 but exclude all others.

e.g. I want to find **myfile1 myfile99** but not **myfile456** and not **myfilebackup**

The regex I'm thinking of is `myfile[1-9]{1,2}` but I can't get this to work with find.

`find . -regex '.*myfile[0-9]{1,2}'`
OR 
`find . -iname 'myfile[0-9]{1,2}'`

From what I can see it's the `{1,2}` part that is not working.

(by the way can you use `-name -regex` interchangably?)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `-iname` (and `-name`) use [globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html), which do not have this syntax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try

```
find . -regex '.*myfile[0-9][0-9]?'
```

or

```
find . \( -name "myfile[0-9][0-9]" -o -name "myfile[0-9]" \)
```

Comment: Thanks - the first line is working for me. I had tried this with -iname but I don't think it supports the syntax or else I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 24):

If you have GNU find, you can use another regular expression type:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '.*myfile[0-9]\{1,2\}'
```

According to GNU `find` uses a [neutered](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/emacs-regular-expression-syntax.html) [Emacs regular expression syntax](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression#toc1) by default - Emacs supports `\{from,to\}` syntax, but at least GNU `find` doesn't support it.

Strangely, the reference manual doesn't include a section on the `sed` regular expression syntax, so who knows which parts of it are supported.

Comment: `sed` like `ed` seems to be an alias for `posix-basic`, so should be compatible with POSIX BRE (though supports some extensions like `\+`). It's not compatible with GNU `sed` where for instance `[\n]` matches a newline instead of the backslash or `n` required by POSIX. See also `-regextype posix-extended` for POSIX EREs (so `.*myfile[0-9]{1,2}`), also with extensions like `\s` or `\<`

Comment: I never knew about -regextype. It seems that if you use `-regextype egrep` it seems like you can avoid the backslashes.

Comment: Sadly, this point about lacking quantifiers (and possibly other features of [the full Emacs regex syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html)) is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, with zero clues whatsoever in [the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).